# Patentsview API Python 3.4

Tags: python, urllib, patentsview

I am beginner in python, currently working on a small project with Python.
I want to build a dynamic script for patent research for patentsview.org.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

#http://www.patentsview.org/api/patents/query?q={"_and":
[{"inventor_last_name":author},{"_text_any":{"patent_title":[title]}}]}&o=
{"matched_subentities_only": "true"}
author = "Jobs"
andreq = "_and"
invln = "inventor_last_name"
text = "_text_any"
patent = "patent_title"
match = "matched_subentities_only"
true = "true"
title = "computer"
urlbasic = "http://www.patentsview.org/api/patents/query"
patentall = {patent:title}
textall = {text:patentall}
invall = {invln:author}
andall = invall.copy()
andall.update(textall)
valuesq = {andreq:andall}
valuesqand = {andreq:andall}
valuesq = {andreq:valuesqand}
valueso = {match:true}

#########
url = "http://www.patentsview.org/api/patents/query"
values = {"q":valuesq,
          "o":valueso}
print(values)


data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
print(data)
############
data = data.encode("UTF-8")
print(data)
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
saveFile = open("patents.txt", "w")
saveFile.write(str(respData))
saveFile.close()
```

I think I got the right start for the dynamic URL - but the encoding seems to give me a HTTP Error 400: Bad request.
If i dont encode, the url will be like [www.somethingsomething.org/o:{....}](http://www.somethingsomething.org/o:%7B....%7D) which obviously produces an error.
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Max/PycharmProjects/KlayerValter/testen.py", line 38, in 
<module>
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I encode, i get the same error since all brackets get converted.
The API of patentsview works as follows:

```
http://www.patentsview.org/api/patents/query?q={"_or":[{"_and":
[{"inventor_last_name":"Whitney"},{"_text_phrase":{"patent_title":"cotton 
gin"}}]},{"_and":[{"inventor_last_name":"Hopper"},{"_text_all":
{"patent_title":"COBOL"}}]}]}
```

For dynamic programming I had to come up with all the library names. If there is also a better solution, please help.

Best Regards.

Comment: Suggestion: use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library instead of fighting with urllib -- it'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api accepts and returns json data, so you should use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to encode your post data. Then use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) on the response if you want a dictionary, or just write to file.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json

url = "http://www.patentsview.org/api/patents/query"
author = "Jobs"
title = "computer"
data = {
    'q':{
        "_and":[
            {"inventor_last_name":author},
            {"_text_any":{"patent_title":title}}
        ]
    }, 
    'o':{"matched_subentities_only": "true"}
}
resp = urlopen(Request(url, json.dumps(data).encode()))
data = resp.read()
#data = json.loads(data)
```

As suggested by Christian, you could simply use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), it's much better than `urllib`.

```
data = requests.post(url, json=data).json()
```

---

As for all those variables in your code, they compose a dictionary like the one below:

```
values = {"q":{andreq:{andreq:{invln:author, text:{patent:title}}}}, "o":{match:true}}
```

I don't see why you would go through all that trouble to build a dictionary but i could be wrong. However you could wrap your code in a function with `author` and `title` as arguments.

---

With `requests` you don't have to use `json.dumps` on your data, just use the `json` parameter. If you want to save the response content to file you should use the `content` or `text` attribute.

```
import requests

title = "computer" 
author = "Jobs" 
url = "http://www.patentsview.org/api/patents/query" 
data = { 
    "q":{ "_and":[ {"inventor_last_name":author}, {"_text_any":{"patent_title":title}}] }, 
    "o":{"matched_subentities_only":"true"} 
} 
resp = requests.post(url, json=data) 
with open("patents.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(resp.text)
```

Comment: " data = requests.post(url, json=data).json() "

This does not work.

resp = requests.post(url, json=data).json()
saveFile = open("patents.txt", "w")
saveFile.write(str(resp))
saveFile.close()

Gives me this:

ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: The `ValueError` exception means that `.json()` failed to decode the response. Please make sure to pass valid data in the `json` parameter. If you update your post with your current code, i could take a look at it.

Comment: import requests
import json
title = "computer"
author = "Jobs"
url = "http://www.patentsview.org/api/patents/query"
data = {
    "q":{
        "and":[
            {"inventor_last_name":author},
            {"_text_any":{"patent_title":title}}]
    },
    "o":{"matched_subentities_only":"true"}
}
var = json.dumps(data)
resp = requests.post(url,data=var)

saveFile = open("patents.txt", "w")
saveFile.write(str(resp))
saveFile.close()


saveFile = open("patents.txt", "w")
saveFile.write(str(resp))
saveFile.close()

Comment: You've mistyped `"_and"`. That causes a 500 ERROR response which is obviously not a json response, so `.json()` fails.  I've updated my post give it a try.

Comment: Thanks - after rewriting, I have overseen this typo.
Ok - I get the Response 200 now - everything is okay according to the server - but where or how do I get the data (e.q. the patents )?
The text file only reads " response 200".

Comment: You can get the [response content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) with `resp.text`. Why don't you use the last snippet in my answer?

Comment: Thanks alot! - It was a long night. Case closed!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to PatentsView, take a look at `patent_client`! It's a python module that searches the live USPTO and EPO databases using a Django-style API. This includes the Patent Examination Data Set that backs the PatentsView API.  The results from any query can then be cast into pandas DataFrames or Series with a simple `.to_pandas()` call.

```py
from patent_client import USApplication

result = USApplication.objects.filter(first_named_inventor="<Name>")

# Returns an iterator of application objects matching the value.
# You can also go directly to a Pandas dataframe with:

result.to_pandas()
```

A great place to start is the [User Guide Introduction](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/)

[image: Patent Client Logo]

[PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/parkerhancock/patent_client) | [Docs](https://patent-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

(Full disclosure - I'm the author and maintainer of patent_client)